# Javascript querySelectorAll get multiple values from multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a website and I want to use multiple inputs

```
<input type="text" class="foo" value="foo">
<input type="text" class="foo" value="foo">
<input type="text" class="foo" value="foo">
...

<button onclick="function()">Send</button>
```

In the Javascript I am using a querySelectorAll to get the values in a array

```
function function() {
   document.querySelectorAll('.foo').value;
}
```

This only work for me when I don’t use a value but then I get the full element and not the value..

Thanks :)

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.foo')` will return nodeList. So `document.querySelectorAll('.foo').value` is undefined.

Comment: `function` is a reserved keyword in javascript.

Comment: @SankarRaj it returns a _`NodeList`_, not a real array.

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Quentin none of the answers in the duplicate question specifically address qSA and its returned `NodeList`.

Comment: @Alnitak —  The context makes it clear that all the methods mentioned in the question work in the same way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a (non-live) [*`NodeList`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not an array.   Fortunately it is possible to `call` the array methods on pseudo-arrays:

```
function getValues(selector) {
    var els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    return [].map.call(els, el => el.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelectorAll('.foo')` will return nodeList. So your code will return `undefined`.

one of the way, you can get array of values.

```js
function func() {
  var a = document.querySelectorAll('.foo');
  var b = [];
  for(var i = 0; i <= a.length-1; i++){
    b.push(a[i].value);
  }
  console.log(b);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="foo" value="foo">
<input type="text" class="foo" value="foo">
<input type="text" class="foo" value="foo">

<button onclick="func()">Send</button>
```

Comment: `.forEach` combined with `push` is a classic anti-pattern (notwithstanding that the `NodeList` interface does offer `.forEach` but doesn't directly support `.map`)

Comment: @Alnitak can you explain sorry, i don't understand

Comment: The canonical way to take an array of something and pass every element through a mutating function, returning a new array of the results is `Array.prototype.map`

Comment: @Alnitak Got it. thanks

Comment: @KadenSkinner, you are trying to check if two array is equal, so this might help - `JSON.stringify(b)==JSON.stringify(["", "foo", "foo"]);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the values individually.
Here is your updated code as an example:

```
function myfunc() {
   var myElementArray = document.querySelectorAll('.foo');

     var myOutputText = "";
     for(var i=0;i< myElementArray.length; i++){
            myOutputText += myElementArray[i].value + " | ";
    }

    alert(myOutputText);
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/775zbjfr/)

Answer (score -1):

With ES6, to get an array of values you can try this

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.foo')).map(x => x.value)
```

Comment: I considered doing that in my own answer, but it unnecessarily creates a whole new array only to throw it away again.  Using `[].map.call` avoids that step.